# Zabbix: Monitor Folder for Files on Windows

Tags: windows, zabbix

I am trying to use Zabbix to monitor a group of Windows servers.

I am new to Zabbix so please give answers with that in mind (for instance, please tell me what to click on in the GUI).

I want to be alerted if there are files in a specific folder at specific times of the day.

Specifically, I have a night time process that is supposed to process all files in a folder.  If it fails it leaves files in that folder.

I have googled and the answers seem to be for Linux or are just to cryptic for me to understand what exactly I should do.

How can I configure Zabbix to alert me to that condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can run periodically from scheduler [fossil-scm](https://www.fossil-scm.org/), it is kinda like [git](https://git-scm.com/), but much simpler and all its functionality is in one single file without any dependencies (BTW, invented by the same author who made SQLite).

First, you need to create initial snapshot

```
cd /to/directory/that/need/to/be/tracked

fossil init nameOfRepository.fossil
fossil open nameOfRepository.fossil
fossil addremove --dotfiles
fossil update
fossil commit --hash -m "Init"
```

then if you would run from scheduler `fossil extras --dotfiles`
you will get list of new (untracked) files.

If you need a list of changed files, you can get it with

```
fossil changes --abs-paths --hash --header -v
```

Redirect output to file and feed with it Zabbix.

P.S.
If you have some automation that deleting automatically files in monitored directory, you need to exclude from deletion in that directory two files:
`nameOfRepository.fossil` and `_FOSSIL_`

Here you can find information how to use custom monitoring on Zabbix clients by utilizing workflow described above: https://www.zabbix.com/custom_monitoring